# AspectRatioFrameLayout duplicate entry in google-vr sdk, when project already uses EXO player library

Tags: google-vr, exoplayer

My application already uses [ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer) from google.
I want to add [google-vr](https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-android-sdk) sdk to it.

But I have got error:

> Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/exoplayer/AspectRatioFrameLayout.class

Problem is that google-vr sdk alredy contains ExoPlayer inside, and I can not modify google-vr sdk as it is distributed as aar android library.

Here  is part of my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    // exo player
    compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r1.5.0'

    // Google VR SDK
    compile project(':gvr-common')
    compile project(':gvr-commonwidget')
    compile project(':gvr-videowidget')
}
```

Would be very happy for any suggestions.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this problem?

Comment: Only exclude compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r1.5.0'
from my dependencies, as it is already included inside google-vr.

But it's version is not 1.5.0 so for me there was compile time errors.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:r2.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:r2.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-hls:r2.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-smoothstreaming:r2.4.0'
```

And keep the minimum sdk version to 21 and remove the Google VR SDK